# How to save a text from a text edit

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Help me I want to complete this code and save text files from text editor in PyQt5 using Qt Widgets. Q File Dialog .get Save File Name. Help me. I Want to write text in text editor and save it but i don't know how to complete Save__File function.

**Code**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(407, 297)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.Text__Edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.Text__Edit.setObjectName("Text__Edit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Text__Edit)
        self.OP_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.OP_Button.setObjectName("OP_Button")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.OP_Button)
        self.SV_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.SV_Button.setObjectName("SV_Button")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.SV_Button)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 407, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.OP_Button.clicked.connect(self.Open__File)
        self.SV_Button.clicked.connect(self.Save__File)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.OP_Button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OpenText"))
        self.SV_Button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SaveText"))

    def Open__File(self):
        O__File = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None,'OpenTextFile','/')
        if O__File[0]:
            in__data = open(O__File[0],'r')
            with in__data:
                Text__ = in__data.read()
                self.Text__Edit.setText(Text__)    

    def Save__File(self):
        S__File = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None,'SaveTextFile','/')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with PyQt but I did a little bit of research and found a solution. There could be a better way to do this though I tested the code and it should work fine.

### Solution

You can use [`toPlainText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#toPlainText) to access the text inside the `QTextEdit`.

**Here is my way.**

```
def Save__File(self):
    # S_File will get the directory path and extension.
    S__File = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None,'SaveTextFile','/', "Text Files (*.txt)")
    
    # This will let you access the test in your QTextEdit
    Text = self.Text__Edit.toPlainText()
    
    # This will prevent you from an error if pressed cancel on file dialog.
    if S__File[0]: 
        # Finally this will Save your file to the path selected.
        with open(S__File[0], 'w') as file:
            file.write(Text)
```

---

I hope this will help you.